# Isolate Mac & Windows sharing parallels

Tags: windows, sharing, parallels-desktop, home-sharing

I am using parallel desktop. Before I installed parallels drivers both were isolated. Now all my folders are shared with Mac and Windows mutually. I can't simply uninstall the drivers because drivers fixed my windows resolution. Now, I am running Windows on Retina Display. Please help me to fix this sharing issue without uninstalling the parallel drivers. I have tried to change the sharing option in preferences options for windows but even that didn't fixed it. Sharing drivers is still their.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Windows VM and go to Actions -> Configure... in the menubar

Choose the Options-tab and highligt `Sharing` in the left pane

Uncheck all boxes like in the picture below:

[image: sharing]

Hit the `Custom Folders...` Button and remove any user-defined OS X folder by highlighting it and clicking the <kbd>-</kbd> button:

[image]